# wxpython popup menu event handler not working

Tags: events, callback, menu, wxpython, handler

So, I have a some simple frame code, note that wx.Frame is *not* subclassed, and the frame runs in the global scope:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

def OnSettings(event):
    print ("'Settings...' selected")

def OnDefaults(event):
    print ("'Defaults...' selected")

def OnPrefs(event):
    print ("'Preferences' selected")

def OnOpen(event):
    print ("'Open...' selected")

def OnClose(event):
    print ("'Close' selected")

def OnCloseAll(event):
    print ("'CloseAll' selected")

def OnNew(event):
    print ("'New...' selected")

def OnQuit(event):
    print ("Quit selected")
    top.Close(True)

def OnExit(event):
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(top, "Do you really want to close this application?", "Confirm Exit", wx.OK|wx.CANCEL|wx.ICON_QUESTION)
    result = dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()
    if result == wx.ID_OK:
       top.Destroy()
    top.Close(True)

def OnRightDown(event):
    top.PopupMenu(rootMenu, event.GetPosition())

rootMenu = wx.Menu()
fileMenu = wx.Menu()

itemNew = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.NewId(), "New...","Create a new instance of something")
fileMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnNew, itemNew)
fileMenu.Append(itemNew)

itemOpen = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.NewId(), "Open...","Open an existing instance of something")
fileMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnOpen, itemOpen)
fileMenu.Append(itemOpen)

fileMenu.AppendSeparator()

itemClose = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.NewId(), "Close","Close whatever is open on top")
fileMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnClose, itemClose)
fileMenu.Append(itemClose)

itemCloseAll = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.NewId(), "Close All","Close everything")
fileMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnCloseAll, itemCloseAll)
fileMenu.Append(itemCloseAll)

rootMenu.AppendSubMenu(fileMenu,"Manage Data","Open, close, or create resources")

configMenu = wx.Menu()

itemSettings = wx.MenuItem(configMenu, wx.NewId(), "Settings...","Configure environmental operating parameters")
configMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnSettings, itemSettings)
configMenu.Append(itemSettings)

itemDefaults = wx.MenuItem(configMenu,wx.NewId(), "Defaults...","Configure default data sources, views, and processing options")
configMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnDefaults, itemDefaults)
configMenu.Append(itemDefaults)

itemPrefs = wx.MenuItem(configMenu,wx.NewId(), "Preferences...","Configure User Interface Cosmetics")
configMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnPrefs, itemPrefs)
configMenu.Append(itemPrefs)

rootMenu.AppendSubMenu(configMenu,"Manage Configuration","Configure Application for operations")

terminalMenu = wx.Menu()

itemExit = wx.MenuItem(terminalMenu,wx.NewId(), "Exit","Terminate after updating and closing anything that's open.")
terminalMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnExit, itemExit)
terminalMenu.Append(itemExit)

itemQuit = wx.MenuItem(terminalMenu,wx.NewId(), "Quit","Close the root window and abandon anything unsaved.")
terminalMenu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, OnQuit, itemQuit)
terminalMenu.Append(itemQuit)

rootMenu.AppendSubMenu(terminalMenu,"Terminate Operations","Exit Session")

top =wx.Frame(None, title="Base Window",size=((1400,875)), style=wx.CAPTION|wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.WS_EX_PROCESS_IDLE)
top.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN, OnRightDown)
top.Centre()
top.Show()
app.SetTopWindow(top)
app.MainLoop()
```

The problem is, none of the event handlers for the menu actually fire. They have to be there, if I comment them out, I get the expected error, but the stubbed handlers dont output to the console and the 'Quit' event dialog (added for testing purposes) does not fire.

What the heck am I missing?

Cheers

Comment: Your code works just fine, when I run it. (Linux, wxpython4.0.3, from the command line)

Comment: Heh, interesting. As it happens, I've got a lovely arch box sitting right beside the windows 10 machine. I'll see about getting this project up and running there and get back to you.

Thanks for the reply BTW :)

Comment: As Mr Robert Burns once said  “the best laid plans of mice and men often go awry”.

Comment: Holy crap, Rolf of Saxony, you are correct Sir. Except for the part where the quit confirmation dialog fails to honor the selected course of action, it behaves completely 'as designed'. That's quite interesting, as on windows this code is 100% fail.

EDIT: Perhaps I should say on /my/ Windows it's 100% fail. Would be interesting to see if any other windows folk have issues; it might well be a purely local, environmental concern.